# Does $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges even though $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been studying sequences and series recently. As I understood, the sequence convergence is determined whether the sequence has a limit value. Now, in this example

$$a_n = \frac{3n^2 - 5n + 7}{3n^3 - 5n + 7}$$

I get $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, which means this sequence converges. What confuses me is that it is known that series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. My question is, is it possible that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges when working with sequences, but diverges when working with series? Or it diverges in both cases?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is unfortunately a *ton* wrong in this question. I think you mean that $a_n \approx. 1/n$, not to have equality. I think you want $\sum a_n$, not $a_n = \sum \frac 1 n$. You should have $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ not $\lim_{x \to \infty}$, and you've mistaken the *sequence* $1/n$ with the series $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: Could you please re-edit the question to make it clear what you're asking?

Comment: The sequence defined by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges, whereas the sequence defined by $b_n = \sum _{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges.

Comment: Why would the limit of the sum of an infinite number of terms have anything to do with the limits of the terms?  $\sum \frac 1n$ is completely different (and obviously much "more") than $\frac 1n$.  After all.  $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1$ diverges to infinity but $1$ is ... as boringly convergent as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

If a series converges, its general term must converge to zero. Indeed, if $s_{0} = 0$, we have:
\begin{align*}
s = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} \Longrightarrow s_{n} - s_{n-1} = a_{n} \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n} & = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (s_{n}-s_{n-1})\\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_{n} - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_{n-1} = s - s = 0 
\end{align*}

However, the converse is not true. As you have noticed, according to the integral criterion, the harmonic series diverges
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = +\infty \Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = +\infty \quad \text{but}\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0
\end{align*}

Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: My question is does 

$$a_n = \frac{3n^2 - 5n + 7}{3n^3 - 5n + 7}$$

converge, since in the end I get $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ and I know that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand your question. Maybe you should edit it.

Comment: I think "converse" is clearer than "reciprocal".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you start walking, and the first step is one meter long. The next two steps are half a meter long. The three steps after that are each one third of a meter long. And so on. The length of your steps get smaller and smaller, and converge to zero. But the total distance you've traveled doesn't converge; it just keeps increasing without bound. It's possible for your speed to converge to zero, without the total distance traveled converging.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1n$ is $\frac 1n$.

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$ is $1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + ....... + \frac 1n$.

Those are completely different things.

> My question is, is it possible that $\frac 1n$ converges when working with sequences, but diverges when working with series?

That question doesn't really make any sense.  "$\frac 1n$" doesn't do anything and isn't a thing that converges.  A sequence (a set listed in order) of $\{1, \frac 12, \frac 13,....\} = \{a_k| a_k = \frac 1k \forall k \in \mathbb N\}$ may converge.  And $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1k = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + .....$ may diverge.  This is because  $\{1, \frac 12, \frac 13,....\} = \{a_k| a_k = \frac 1k \forall k \in \mathbb N\}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1k = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + .....$ are two entirely different things.

This is akin to $57 + 39 + 6$ is a different thing than $57,39, 6$.

It's pretty easy to convince oneself that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = 0$.  The terms $\frac 1n$ get increassingly smaller but no matter how small a value we compare the terms to we can find a $\frac 1n$ term that is smaller.

Or in other more technical terms.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $n > \frac 1\epsilon$ where $0 < \frac 1n < \epsilon$ and that is true for any $\epsilon$ no matter how small but positive.

It's less obvious that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1k$ diverges but this is a sum and we keep adding on to it.  It doesn't matter that the terms we keep adding on might converge down to something as we are considering the *sum* of terms; not just the current term we are adding.

In this case although the individual terms "go to zero", they don't go to zero "fast enough".  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1k = 1 + (\frac 12 + \frac 13) + (\frac 14 + \frac 15 + \frac 16 + \frac 17) + ...... + (\frac 1{2^n} + \frac 1{2^n + 1} + .... + \frac 1{2^n + (2^n -1)}) + .....  > \frac 12 + (\frac 14 + \frac 14) + (\frac 18 + \frac 18 + \frac 18 + \frac 18) + ...... (\frac 1{2^{n+1}} + \frac 1{2^{n+1}} + .... + \frac 1{2^{n+1}}) + ... = \frac 12 + \frac 12 + .... + \frac 12 + .....$ which clearly diverges.